# SharePoint 2007: populating listColumns with information from MySites/User Profiles

Tags: 2007, list, user-profile

Can anyone advise if it's possible to populate a list column with information from either a MySite or the User Profiles, specificaly the Department.  My scenario is that an internal client is 100% deadset against the use of MySites but still wants to populate a list with some of the data stored within them.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are pretty limited in 2007. You could write custom code to call the UserProfileService.asmx web service, but without a bit more detail I can only offer vague recommendations.

Comment: Hi Matthew,  The requirement is simply to display a user's department within a SharePoint list, ideally upon  a list item submission.

Comment: I can't remember if its an option in 2007, can you set the Department to "replicate" so that it is published to the User Info List? (It works in 2010) Then you have the info in the Site Collection for use in your list. Worth a try.